# Loading a view makes the program crash

Tags: xcode, swift, view, viewcontroller, fatal-error

I'm still learning how the view works, but I found a problem that I couldn't solve...
I got the class `GraficsBalancGlobalViewController`which is subclass of the class `GraficViewController`

```
class GraficsBalancGlobalViewController: GraficViewController {
  @IBAction func afegeixGrafic(sender: NSButton) {
    addNewGrafic() // which is set on the GraficViewController
  }
}
```

And when I perform the IBAction `afegeixGrafic` my program crashes on the line marked below:

```
class GraficViewController: NSViewController, GraficViewDataSource {

  @IBAction func button(sender: NSButton) {
    addNewGrafic()
  }

  func addNewGrafic() {
    let frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width , height: self.view.bounds.width * 0.25)
    let nouGrafic = GraficView(frame: frame)
    scrollView.addSubview(nouGrafic) <---- BREAK here!
  }

  @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: NSView!
  //...more code
}
```

The compiler says that:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

but the button (IBAction) inside the `GraficViewController` works well!! So i suppose that the problem is related with the scrollView, but I have no idea of what can be.. It is initialized..

- just to mention that the `GraficView(frame: frame)`is not the problem because I try it and works well.

Comment: Did you check your `IBOutlet` for the `scrollView`?

Comment: Add a breakpoint at this line and on break type "p scrollView" into the debugger console. Is scrollView nil?

Comment: @Drako Yes! you are right scrollView is nill, but it exists, it's on the screen!

Comment: I found that in the case of the `@IBAction func button` the scrollView is not nil!, I really don't know why.. when performing the other @IBAction don't work...

Answer (score 0):

I do believe `!` is the culprit of your woes:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: NSView!
```

Xcode does generate this entry with force unwrap (`!`) for `IBOutlet`s, but it should really be an optional (`?`) because you have no guaranties *when* that reference is going to be set.  If you have some logic that depend on `scrollView`'s existence, you can do so by relying on `didSet`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: NSView? {
    didSet {
        guard let sview = scrollView else {
            return // because scrollView is nil for some reason
        }
        // do your scrollView existence dependent logic here (eg. reload content)
    }
}

func addNewGrafic() {
    let frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width , height: self.view.bounds.width * 0.25)
    let nouGrafic = GraficView(frame: frame)
    scrollView?.addSubview(nouGrafic)
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Actually I have no existence dependent logic yet. Using the changes, without writing anything there `// do your scrollView existence dependent logic here (eg. reload content)` when I click the @IBAction `afegeixGrafic` apear nothing on the view. What I wanted is that apear the new view inside the scroll view, maybe I'm so wrong about this..

Comment: How can be possible that the scrollview is nil when using the first:`@IBAction afegeixGrafic` but when using `@IBAction func button`it isn't'?

Comment: There is no guaranty that states these outlets/actions are set in certain/dependable sequence.  Try the above (with the recent edit)

Comment: It helps, because the program don't crash now, but the view doesn't apear.. And that is because the scrollView is empty (nil) when i use it in the `@IBAction afegeixGrafic` i'm not sure how to solve it.

Comment: put a debugging statements (_eg_ `NSLog` because it prints time and printed in sequence) in `didSet` and `addNewGrafic` to determine the sequence of event.  It may be possible that outlets were connected incorrectly as well.